# IPFS nodes in Docker and Web UI

Tags: ipfs, webui

This question is referred to the following project which is about [Integrating Fabric Blockchain and IPFS](https://github.com/IBM/IPFSfB).

The architecture basically comprises a swarm of docker containers that should communicate with each other (Three containers: Two peer nodes and one Server node). Every container is an IPFS node and has a separate configuration.

I am trying to run a dockerized environment of an IPFS cluster of nodes and view the WEB UI that comes with it. I set up the app by running all the steps described and then supposedly i would be able to see the WebUI in this address:

> http://127.0.0.1:5001

Everything seem to be setup and configured as they should (I checked every `docker logs <container>`). Nevertheless all i get is an empty page.

When i try to view my local IPFS repository via

> https://webui.ipfs.io/#/welcome

I get a message that this is probably caused by a CORS error (it makes sense) and it is suggested to change the IPFS configuration in order to by-pass the CORS error. See [this](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-webui#configure-ipfs-api-cors-headers)!

**Screenshot**

[image]

I try to implement the solution by changing the Headers in the configuration but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The confusion relies on the fact that after setting up the containers we have 3 different containers with 3 configurations and in addition the IPFS daemon is running in each one of them. Outside the containers the IPFS Daemon is not running.

- I don't know if the IPFS daemon outside the containers should be running.
- I'm not sure which configuration (if not all) should i modify.
- Should i use a reverse proxy to solve this?

### Useful Info

The development is done in a Linux-Ubuntu VM that meets all the necessary requirements.